# Combined width sprintf

Tags: php, formatting, printf

I have two strings I want to combine and have not exceed a certain width.

```
$string = sprintf("%4(%s %s)", $s1, $s2);
//s1 s
```

Notice how the combined %s %s did not exceed a width of 4.

How can I do this with sprintf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add more detail to your question - what do you want to happen if the fields are longer than 3 characters (4 - one space)?

But maybe this is what you want:

```
sprintf("%.4s", "$s1 $s2");
```

That will output the combined string `"$s1 $s2"`, pruned to 4 characters.  Of course substr would do the same, this might be useful in the context of a longer format string.

To be honest I hadn't realised before that the precision specifier (`.` followed by number) could be used with `%s`.

Comment: Currently I have them concat'd now (like you did), but I thought there might be a way in (s)printf. Thanks!

Comment: @tau, the alternative would maybe calculating the padding width with strlen, that would give you more flexibility (eg if you wanted to left justify `$s1` and right-justify `$s2`, but to share as much space as possible).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how to do so with sprintf but you can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to do so;

```
$string = substr("$s1 $s2",0,4);
```

This should return the same result